# Ionic 2 project not working on new computer

Tags: angular, ionic2

I've changed my computer to a new one and tried to install all the stuff to run my ionic 2 project, everything is ok and up-to-date but for some reason I'm getting the following error when i run `ionic serve -l`

```html
Uncaught TypeError: jit_val_0 is not a function
    at eval (ng:///AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:3)
    at evalExpression (compiler.es5.js:26569)
    at jitStatements (compiler.es5.js:26581)
    at JitCompiler._compileModule (compiler.es5.js:26862)
    at compiler.es5.js:26801
    at Object.then (compiler.es5.js:1683)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.es5.js:26799)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.es5.js:26728)
    at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (core.es5.js:4811)
    at PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (core.es5.js:4797)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just   update  angular modules to 4.4.4

```
npm install @angular/core@latest
```

Comment: Yes... that worked, my `npm install` didn't run correctly